# Kotlin Configuration error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I have started  kotlin programing in android.I setup the kotlin in android studio.But gradle failed to build project. Kotlin reflection lib error.

Here is my Logcat:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   C:\Users\USER.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\gradle-4.1\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.1.4\27053164a2b459671c4b9fe791408a5bc064937f\kotlin-reflect-1.1.4.jar
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error
>   while dexing. Error:java.util.NoSuchElementException Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
> >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
> >     process
> >     C:\Users\USER.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\gradle-4.1\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.1.4\27053164a2b459671c4b9fe791408a5bc064937f\kotlin-reflect-1.1.4.jar
> >     Information:BUILD FAILED in 19s Information:4 errors Information:0
> >     warnings Information:See complete output in console

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codefuelindia.healthcircleordermgmt"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            postprocessing {
                removeUnusedCode false
                removeUnusedResources false
                obfuscate false
                optimizeCode false
                proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4"

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

How to solve..Need help.

Comment: Post your gradle files both project and module

Comment: This may be an issue in KOTLIN configuration wizard that is fixed in newer plugin versions. Better you can move to Android Studio 3.0 for KOTLIN.

Comment: Already using android 3.0

Comment: can u please try to sync gradle after removing compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4" and espresso and test:runner dependency ? let me know if u still face issue...please remove those 3 dependency first..than file-> invalidate cache and restart the studio

Comment: When I remove  "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4" error gone But I need to use "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4" for getting classname

Comment: let me post that solution below so other can also use it...i will guide for getting classname

Comment: Not solved..i have tried invalid cache and restart and synch.Any Other Solution.?Any other way to get class name in kotlin?

Comment: @NiravShah compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect" can you try this dependency?

Comment: other way for getting class name is you can add jar file for it i already posted link in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158375/discussion-between-lokesh-desai-and-nirav-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync your gradle after Just removing compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4" than file-> invalidate cache and restart option from the studio

For getting classname please refer below link.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html